# The Honest Guard

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Three prisoners were blindfolded and given a shovel.

The sick and twisted guard told the three men: “No matter what happens tonight, at least one man is certain to die. However, it will not be the man with the deepest grave. But, if any of you begin to dig, only the man with the deepest grave will survive. If none of you dig, only one man will die.”

With no murders or suicides, the three prisoners survived the night.

The guard’s honest husband, who was just as twisted, said the guard was always truthful. How can this be?

Comment: This is very similar to a [riddle on reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/riddles/comments/2zwnl4/sicktwisted/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the guard said

> "If none of you dig, only one man will die," he didn't specify which man

so I'm guessing that

> None of the prisoners dug, and the honest guard died of a terminal illness

Answer (score 4):

> None of them dug.  The guard's husband died of natural causes.

Comment: A good guess as he was "*sick* and twisted"

Answer (score 1):

> All of them dug, and all the graves were exactly the same depth. The guard had said that only *the man* with the deepest grave would die. There is no such man, so no one dies.

Comment: The guard said "No matter what happens tonight, *at least one man is certain to die*" so this does not answer the riddle properly